# Why wont this table create

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to create the following table but it wont create??

```
use [TagHolderDB]
CREATE TABLE TBLSearchTags 
(
  TagID int(11), --NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Tagterm varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  Tagcounter int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  TaglastSearch datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (TagID),
  --KEY Tagterm  (Tagterm)
) --ENGINE=TagHolderDB;
```

The Current error is:

> Msg 2716, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Column, parameter, or variable #1:
>   Cannot specify a column width on data type int.

There is also different errors when i move away the comments  --

I need it all to work as i am following a tutorial, Could some one tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Errors when i remove the -- comments:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4 Incorrect syntax near
>   'AUTO_INCREMENT'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'KEY'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10 Incorrect syntax near '='.

If someone could explain to me what ENGINE does that would be great to.

Comment: The solution is in the error message.

Comment: Could you show me what you mean?

Comment: looks like a MySQL table defintion (not sql server)

Comment: Thanks Mitch Wheat, Yes it is MySql, i did not know there was a diffrence. So how would i go about switching it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Int datatype does not have length.

Try this:

```
use [TagHolderDB]
CREATE TABLE TBLSearchTags 
(
  TagID int, --NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Tagterm varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  Tagcounter int NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  TaglastSearch datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (TagID),
  --KEY Tagterm  (Tagterm)
) --ENGINE=TagHolderDB;
```

Comment: Thanks it created, will this lose any functionality, to the table i was first trying to create, because as i stated i'm following a tutorial, i don't want to get to the end and have it not work.

Comment: Although this would not work in SQL-Server since your default date is invalid. **Edit**: Only just seen in the comments that OP actually uses MySql.

Comment: @Pomster the tutorial might be wrong or is from other version of MYSQL. Check the "int" datatypes here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is self-explanatory.

> You cannot specify a column width on data type int.

A SQL integer always takes 4 bytes of storage, ranging from -2147483648 to 2147483647.

So replace `int(11)` with `int`.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TBLSearchTags](
    [TagID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Tagterm] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [TagCounter] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_TBLSearchTags_TagCounter]  DEFAULT ((1)),
    [TaglastSearch] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_TBLSearchTags_TaglastSearch]  DEFAULT ('1753-01-01'),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TBLSearchTags] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [TagID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Thanks, will this lose any functionality, to the table i was first trying to create, because as i stated i'm following a tutorial, i don't want to get to the end and have it not work

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

do

```
IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
```

and replace `int(11)` with `int`:

```
use [TagHolderDB]
CREATE TABLE TBLSearchTags 
(
  TagID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  Tagterm varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  Tagcounter int NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  TaglastSearch datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (TagID)
)
```

Comment: Thanks, will this lose any functionality, to the table i was first trying to create, because as i stated i'm following a tutorial, i don't want to get to the end and have it not work